# Подскажите почему таблица не видит выбор JRadioButton

Tags: java

первый фрейм:

```
public class AppDirectoryMainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private ButtonGroup rbg;
private JPanel panel1;
private static final String DEFAULT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT";
    public AppDirectoryMainFrame(){
    setTitle("AppDirectory");
    setSize(550, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),
                    "Справочники"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)));

    rbg = new ButtonGroup();

    addRadioButton("Подразделения", "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT");
    addRadioButton("Сотрудники", "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP");
    addRadioButton("Разрядная сетка", "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.SALGRADE");

    JButton selectButton = new JButton("Выбор");
    selectButton.setToolTipText("Подтвердить выбор справочника");
    selectButton.addActionListener(new SelectButtonActionListener());

    GridBagConstraints c4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c4.gridx = 1;
    c4.gridy = 3;
    c4.gridwidth = 1;
    c4.gridheight = 1;
    c4.weightx = 0.0;
    c4.weighty = 0.0;
    c4.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    c4.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c4.insets = new Insets(1, 160, 1, 1);
    c4.ipadx = 0;
    c4.ipady = 0;
    panel1.add(selectButton, c4);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),
                    "Отчеты"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)));
    JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox("Суммарная зарплата всех"
            + " сотрудников подразделений");
    checkBox1.setSelected(true);
    JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox("Сотрудники, имеющие зарплату"
            + " выше средней в своем подразделении");
    JButton reportButton = new JButton("Отчет");
    reportButton.setToolTipText("Подтвердить выбор отчета");
    reportButton.addActionListener(new ReportButtonActionListener());

    GridBagConstraints c5 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c5.gridx = 0;
    c5.gridy = 0;
    c5.gridwidth = 1;
    c5.gridheight = 1;
    c5.weightx = 0.0;
    c5.weighty = 0.0;
    c5.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c5.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c5.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    c5.ipadx = 0;
    c5.ipady = 0;
    panel2.add(checkBox1, c5);
    GridBagConstraints c6 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c6.gridx = 0;
    c6.gridy = 1;
    c6.gridwidth = 1;
    c6.gridheight = 1;
    c6.weightx = 0.0;
    c6.weighty = 0.0;
    c6.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c6.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c6.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    c6.ipadx = 0;
    c6.ipady = 0;
    panel2.add(checkBox2, c6);
    GridBagConstraints c7 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c7.gridx = 1;
    c7.gridy = 2;
    c7.gridwidth = 1;
    c7.gridheight = 1;
    c7.weightx = 0.0;
    c7.weighty = 0.0;
    c7.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c7.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c7.insets = new Insets(15, 1, 1, 1);
    c7.ipadx = 0;
    c7.ipady = 0;
    panel2.add(reportButton, c7);

    ButtonGroup gc1 = new ButtonGroup();
    gc1.add(checkBox1);
    gc1.add(checkBox2);

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public void addRadioButton(String name, final String query){
        boolean selected = query == DEFAULT_QUERY;
        JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(name, selected);
        rbg.add(button);
        panel1.add(button);

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
                dbtm.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println(query);
            }
        };
        button.addActionListener(listener);
    }    
}
```

второй фрейм с таблицей:

```
public class ViewFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static final String DEFAULT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT"; 
public ViewFrame(){
    setTitle("AppDirectory");
    setSize(700, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel dbTablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
    JTable dbTable=new JTable(dbtm);

    dbtm.executeQuery(DEFAULT_QUERY);

    JScrollPane dbTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(dbTable);
    dbTableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 250));

    dbTablePanel.add(dbTableScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 3, 1, 2,
            1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
            new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Ввод");
    addButton.setToolTipText("Ввести новые данные в таблицу");
    JButton editButton = new JButton("Редактировать");
    editButton.setToolTipText("Редактировать существующую запись");
    JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Удалить");
    deleteButton.setToolTipText("Удалить данные из таблицы");
    JButton dropButton = new JButton("Очистить");
    dropButton.setToolTipText("Очистить таблицу");
    dropButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    dropButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    buttonPanel.add(addButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
    buttonPanel.add(editButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
    buttonPanel.add(deleteButton, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
    buttonPanel.add(dropButton, new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                    new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));

    add(dbTablePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(false);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь вы создали *новую* модель данных таблицы, выполнили на ней запрос, а потом про нее забыли.

```
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
    "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
                dbtm.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println(query);
            }
        };
```

В `ViewFrame` вы создали таблицу, получающую данные из модели, которая больше нигде не видна.

```
DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
JTable dbTable=new JTable(dbtm);
```

В результате у вас в программе гуляет *несколько разных экземпляров* моделей таблицы, и действия с одним из них не отображаются на других.

Вам нужно как-то обеспечить передачу запроса в модель, по которой строится таблица в ViewFrame. Можно в ViewFrame выделить модель в отдельное поле и добавить метод типа

```
public void executeQuery(String query) {
    dbtm.executeQuery(query);
}
```

после чего вызывать его из `ActionListener`.

Я не вижу в `AppDirectoryMainFrame` ссылок на `ViewFrame`, поэтому не очень понимаю, как и где все эти окна создаются, и через что друг с другом связаны.

Comment: Вот мой проект: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4q9yD9x-Mo2X0txUGZnRFRsdjA
можешь по смотреть и посоветовать что сделать, а то я запутался уже

Comment: с несколькими гулящими моделями таблиц, на это я не обратил внимания, спасибо большое)